# After making a number of wiki edits I can't propose new edits

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags

I noticed a repeated grammar mistake in all country tags.

So I went through them one by one editing them or adding a description if there is not already.

After a number of edits, I found the edit button disappeared.

I bet this is a safety feature to prevent spamming the review queues.

But what about a person like me?

An answer like tell a higher-reputation-person / moderator the issue for him to do it, I would reply with either they might be doing something more important like answering a question or I want to get reputation and want to earn the [`Research Assistant`](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant) badge.

**EDIT**:

I noticed that when keeping an edit window open and after finishing the limit clicking the save button it will prompt:

> You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved.

Comment: On that note, some of your suggestions are incorrect, or merely copypasted from other tags. I have rejected some for that reason.

Comment: I'm going to object to your mass tag wiki edits. They are just copy pastes of saying "answer to what an average Canadian person" would do. They don't add to the content of the tag wiki, which is to explain the subject of the tag. The edits are, without intending any offence, worthless, since they don't add to the value of the site.

Comment: yes they are copy pasted from other tags

Comment: do you really think that @Zizouz212

Comment: Also, some tags are common sense, we don't need a specific wiki for each and every tag. But, **I'm happy you're willing to ask and learn. +1 for that.**

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz Yes, I really do. I'm not blaming you for doing so though - there's another user who did the same thing which I guess you're modelling off of, so please don't take my words personally. I'm just saying that generic wikis don't often add much more than nothing.

Comment: I guess you right @Zizouz212 , and about the user I have never seen any similar behavior

Comment: a tag like java https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java

Comment: is this an error confused with Java programming language or Java island @Zizouz212

Comment: I don't mind empty tag wiki excerpts getting content. I don't think they all need to be identical, though, so I'm not going to approve changing an existing and useful excerpt to just match the others.

Comment: I guess that is right @Catija don't accept them

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz Java island in Indonesia.

Comment: should it be a synonym of Indonesia @Zizouz212

Comment: @Catija If that was a comment to me, then I'm not talking about excerpts (in those cases, I kind of agree that we have at least something there, even if it's intuitive), but I'm more referring to actual tag wiki's, such as this: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1957 Which is really a generic piece of text that doesn't serve to explain the actual content/subject of the tag.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz Nope. The more specific, the better. Not to big of a deal.

Comment: @Catija if such behavior was done in a busier SE site like StackOverflow would that be considered spamming and would the person get suspended?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yeah. I wasn't a fan of those, either. I agree that wikis don't really need content if the excerpt is good. I approved a couple of them but not all. Omar, I don't use SO, so I'm not sure what would happen. Probably just edit banned, not suspended. We try to make punishment fit the "crime", so lots of rejected edit suggestions leads to an edit ban.

Comment: Ahh I forgot about edit bans @Catija

Comment: @Zizouz212 thanks for pointing that out. I've changed my tag to "javanese" instead of the confusing "java" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a bug. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Users who have under a certain amount of reputation can only have [20 suggested edits on a beta site:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits/281202#281202)

From Shog9's answer:

> As of a few seconds ago, this limit is now active network-wide:
>
> - at-most **20 pending suggested edits** per editor on beta sites
> - at-most **5 pending suggested edits** per editor on graduated sites
>
> These limits are based on my analysis of the speed at which edits are generally approved and the number of edits (and editors) that would have been affected over the past few months. They can be adjusted if it becomes necessary.

Until your edits are reviewed, you can not make any more. Once the number of suggested edits drops, you will again be able to submit edit suggestions.

Read more: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/)

Comment: as an extra information: can't a moderator increase the amount or should all the moderators agree on it, and if yes can he do that for only one user as an exception

Comment: No. It's set by the system. We have no control over this. It is already increased on Beta sites to 20 instead of 5.

Comment: thanks for the information

Comment: I'm clearing a bunch of your edits, though, so you should be able to submit more. There aren't many people with sufficient reputation to approve tag wiki edits, though. Also, you should note that there is a cap on the amount of reputation that can be earned from edit suggestions.

Comment: understood, I am almost done

Comment: The rep cap via edit suggestions is 1000. @OmarAbdelhafiz See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/309993

Comment: thanks for the knowledge @NVZ